# (Firebase/angularfire2) getting [object Object] error when dowloading URL

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

i'm getting an error when trying to get the URL from a file that i just uploaded.

This one:

> uncaught exception: [object Object]

This is my code in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {

ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
task: AngularFireUploadTask;
uploadProgress: Observable<number>;
downloadURL: Observable<string | null>;
taskName:string;
id:string;

ngOnInit() {

}

constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage){

}

upload(event) {
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    this.ref = this.afStorage.ref('myURL/'+this.id);
    this.task =  this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
    this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
    this.downloadURL = this.afStorage.ref('myURL/'+this.id).getDownloadURL();
}

}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    Firebase Cloud Storage Angular
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Select a file for upload</h5>
    <input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" accept=".png, .jpg,"/>
    <div class="progress">
        <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-succes" role="progressbar" [style.width]="(uploadProgress | async) + '%'" [attr.aria-valuenow]="(uploadProgress | async)" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div *ngIf="downloadURL | async; let downloadSrc" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        File uploaded: <a [href]="downloadSrc">{{downloadSrc}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now... you don't need to tell me, i realized that this is because .getDownloadURL is executing at the same time when the file is being uploaded. I know this because when i assign that function to a normal button and wait for the file to upload to press it, the link appears just fine.

I followed some tutorials, but none of them appeared to have this same problem.

¿How can i know when the file has been succesfully uploaded?

Thank you very much and sorry for my not that great english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Rahul and Mauricio i was able to find a solution to my problem:

```
const task = this.afStorage.upload('myURL/'+this.id,event.target.files[0]);
task.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
  this.downloadURL = this.afStorage.ref('myURL/'+this.id).getDownloadURL();
});
```

It first asks if the URL of the task is avaible and then it declares the downloadURL.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to subscribe to the observable task.downloadURL():

```
upload(event) {
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    this.ref = this.afStorage.ref('myURL/'+this.id);
    this.task =  this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
    this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
    this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
        console.log('Your url is ready to use:', url);
    });
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio throws an error and says that i can't assign a subscription to an observable. It's missing _isScalar, but i don't really know what that means.

Comment: I deleted a comment saying that i fixed it, but apparently it just worked that one time. How weird.

Comment: nvm i just did it.
Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
upload(event) {
    const task = this.afStorage.upload('myURL/'+this.id,event.target.files[0]);
    this.uploadProgress = task.percentageChanges();
    this.downloadURL = task.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
        console.log('Your url is ready to use:', url);
    });
}
```